# Regression line from Anova-table

Tags: regression, anova, regression-coefficients

[image] - I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get the value of
   $\beta$ for regression line from Anova-table. So far i see that SST =
   SSE + SSM  which is equal to (SST = $\sum(y_i-\bar y))$ but i don't
   understand from where do i get the value of $(x_i - \bar x)$
   because $\beta $ value is calculated by $\frac{(y_i - \bar y)}{(x_i
   - \bar x)}$ which is slope.
Picture of ANova , [image]

Comment: Please display an example of the ANOVA table you are referring to.

Comment: You don't get the regression line from the table. Where did this idea come from? (For a simple regression, you can get the correlation coefficient, r, from the ANOVA table.)

Comment: $SST = SSM + SSE$ which is equal to $(y_i - \bar y)$ and $\beta = \frac{(y_i - \bar y)}{(x_i - \bar x)}$ i was thinking if it was possible to get $(x_i - \bar x)$ also :(